# React Three Fiber | Lines are not casting shadows

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

I recently started digging into ThreeJS, followed some tutorials and now I have a problem with my line / bufferGeometry not casting any shadows. Shadows are casted, as long as I use boxBufferGeometry inside a mesh. But if I use lines, nothing happens

```
import React from 'react'
import { Canvas } from '@react-three/fiber'
import Curve from './components/Curve';
import Controls from './components/Controls';
import Plane from './components/Plane';
import * as THREE from 'three';


const App = () => {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Canvas shadows colorManagement camera={{position: [5,5,5]}} onCreated={({gl}) => {
                gl.shadowMap.enabled = true;
                gl.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFShadowMap;
                gl.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio || 2);
            }}>
                <spotLight 
                    position={[0,70,0]}
                    color="white"
                    intensity={1.5}
                    castShadow 
                    shadowMapHeight={1024}
                    shadowMapWidth={1024}
                    shadowCameraNear={200}
                    shadowCameraFar={2000}
                    shadowBias={ - 0.00022} 
                    angle={0.01}
                />
                <ambientLight color="#f0f0f0" />
                <Controls />
                <Curve />
                <Plane />
                <gridHelper args={[30, 100, 'white', 'white']} position={[0,-3.99,0]} receiveShadow />
            </Canvas>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

```
import React, { useLayoutEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import * as THREE from 'three';

const Curve = () => {
    const curve = new THREE.CubicBezierCurve3
        (
            new THREE.Vector3( -10, 0, 0 ),
            new THREE.Vector3( -5, 15, 0 ),
            new THREE.Vector3( 20, 15, 0 ),
            new THREE.Vector3( 10, 0, 0 ) 
        ); 

    const points = curve.getPoints( 50 );

    const ref = useRef()
    useLayoutEffect(() => {void ref.current.setFromPoints(points); }, [points])

    return (
    <line>
        <bufferGeometry ref={ref} />
        <lineBasicMaterial color={0xd2452b} />
      </line>

       
    );
};

export default Curve;
```

```
import React from 'react';


const Plane = () => 
    <mesh rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]} position={[0,-4,0]} receiveShadow>
        <planeGeometry 
            attach="geometry"
            args={[1024,1024]}
        />
        <shadowMaterial attach="material" color="#000000" opacity="1" />
    </mesh>

export default Plane;
```

Rendering this component (Box) instead of curve, would cast a shadow.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useSpring, a } from '@react-spring/three';

const Box = () => {

    const [hovered, setHovered] = useState(false);
    const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
    const props  = useSpring({
        scale: active ? 2 : 1,
        color: hovered ? 'red' : 'gray',
    });

    return (
        <a.mesh 
            onPointerOver={() => setHovered(true)}
            onPointerOut={() => setHovered(false)}
            onClick={() => setActive(!active)}
            scale={props.scale}
            castShadow
        >
            <boxBufferGeometry 
                attach="geometry"
                args={[1,1,1]}
            />
            <a.meshPhysicalMaterial attach="material" color={props.color} />
        </a.mesh>
    );
};

export default Box;
```

The only difference (I'm still a newbie), is that I am using lines instead of mesh. Mesh accepts attributes like "receiveShadow and castShadow", lines doesn't.
How do I manage to let my lines cast shadows, too?

Thanks a lot in advance